# What are the prerequisites to learn Spintronics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, education

I am interested in Spintronics and recently started reading Spintronics' articles. I found that there are a lot of terms that I don't understand in those papers, for example, Spin Transfer Torque, LLG equation, Keldysh contour, propagators, Green's function correlator etc.

I have complete BS Physics, so I have basic knowledge of Quantum Mechanics, Solid State Physics and Mathematical Physics.

What are the books/courses/theories that I need to learn to understand research articles (especially the ones which are related to non-equilibrium transport properties) of spintronics?

Answer (score 0):

To understand many of the concepts in spin transport properties it will be useful to familiarize yourself with concepts about magnetostatics, spin and consequences of spin property of electrons, exchange interaction, ferromagnetism, energies and anisotropies in magnetic materials, so on. These topics will be covered in books on magnetism and magnetic materials. Following are some amazing books to refer -

1. Magnetism and Magnetic materials by J. M. D. Coey.
2. Magnetism in Condensed Matter by Stephen Blundell.
3. Introduction to magnetic materials by Cullity and Graham.

To study spin-transport it will be useful to begin with Ferromagnetic resonance, spin currents, magnetoresistance effects. Some great books and papers -

1. Introduction to magnetic materials by Cullity and Graham.
2. Nanomagnetism and Spintronics edited by Teruya Shinjo
3. Magnetism and magnetic materials by J. M. D. Coey

Hope this is helpful! :)